# Application is not working on 10.6

Tags: macos, cocoa, compatibility

I'm currently working on a port of my Windows game for Mac OS X, it runs fine on my Mac when compiled with Xcode 4.5.2 on OS X 10.8, but it crashes on a friends Mac running 10.6. At first I thought it was due to one of the Frameworks I've been using, but the standard Cocoa app template crashes at well, without any visible error message.

I already tried setting the Deployment Target to 10.5, but this doesn't change anything. When starting the App, it appears for a short time in the Dock and then disappears without showing any kind of UI or error message.

Comment: Can you please take a look into the Console app (`/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`) and paste the relevant error information here?

Comment: Here's a wild guess based on the standard template not working....  Do you have .xib files with Auto Layout turned on?

Comment: You should do what @JustSid mentions above. You'll likely see a crash log with little or no stack that says there was a dyld or dylib error loading a particular dynamic library.

Comment: I have to wait for my friend to ask him to look into the Console app. I will give you the answer soon. @PhillipMills : I have the MainMenu.xib but there is nothing in it, it is really just the template.